# How to find out all the patches applied between two git branches?

Tags: git, patch, git-branch, git-diff

I want to find out all the patches that have been applied between two git branches. I tried 
 the commands below, but that didn't work out for me.

```
git diff 1.6..1.4 | grep  -r  -i  --include *\.patch
```

How can I find out all the patches that have been committed between two git branches?

Comment: Please be specific about what "patches" means here.  How, for instance, would you go about doing this manually?

Comment: @jthill,let me put what I am trying to do,to do deliver a particular feature there are some changes made between branch 1.4 to 1.6 ,so I wanted to capture all those changes but not sure how I go about it?eckes answer helped me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to get **all commits that were made** between `1.4` (*older* branch/tag/revision) and `1.6` (*newer* branch/tag/revision):

```
git log 1.4..1.6
```

The [docs of `git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) provide more information how to control the output of `git log`.

If you want to watch the commits not on the command line but in a graphical frontend, use the builtin `gitk`:

```
gitk 1.4..1.6
```

---

The reason why your `git diff` command is not the right choice here is that `git diff` shows differences in the files of the revisions (i.e. the difference in file `foo.txt` between `1.4` and `1.6`) while `git log` roughly shows the commit messages introduced between `1.4` and `1.6`.

The output of `git diff` is simply the **patch file content** that would be needed in order to bring `1.4` to `1.6`, therefore your `grep` statement won't match anything ever:

```
git diff 1.4..1.6 > patch_from_1.4_to_1.6.patch
git apply patch_from_1.4_to_1.6.patch
```

After applying this patch on your `1.4` version, **the files** of `1.4` and `1.6` **would be equal** and your branch would hold **one commit** that is needed for this equality.

The output of `git log` are the **commits** that would be needed in order to bring `1.4` to `1.6`. In order to bring `1.4` to `1.6`, you would use `git format-patch`:

```
git format-patch 1.4..1.6 # will create a set of patches that represent the commits
git am -- *.patch # will apply these patches in the right sequence
```

After applying these patches, your `1.4` based branch will not have the **same file contents** as the `1.6` branch but will also hold **all commits** that were made between `1.4` and `1.6`.

Comment: ,is there any way to find only patch files that have committed between 1.4 and 1.6?

Comment: there is no way to check which commits were applied through patch files vs. which commits were introduced through, say, typing them. See updated answer for more clearification.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: or does your repo contain `.patch` files that are versioned and you want to check which commit touched a `.patch` file?: `git log --oneline 1.4..1.6 -- *.patch`

Comment: for some commits between 1.4 and 1.6 there are only patches are applied ,I just wanted to list down these .patch files.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079613/how-to-find-out-all-patch-appiled-between-two-git-branches/25079930?noredirect=1#comment39020799_25079930 This is not possible.